# Why terminal doesn't prompt another input for this JAVA code?

Tags: java

```
class test {
 public static void main(String args[])
  throws java.io.IOException {

    char ch, answer = 'K';

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
    System.out.print("Can you guess it: ");

    ch = (char) System.in.read();

    if(ch == answer) {
     System.out.println(" *** YOU ARE RIGHT *** ");   
       else System.out.println("Please try again: ");
        ch = (char) System.in.read();        
   }
  }

}
```

I'm using command line to run this java program and I want the user to continuously be able to input something instead of having to run the program manually every time they guess it wrongly. Tried many ways but the second `System.in.read()` doesn't show a prompt instead the code just ends in terminal having to manually run the program again to play. I'm a beginner so I have trouble understanding.

Comment: Because your indentation is wrong. The else has one statement, the following read is *not* constrained any more. Rather use { braces) to clearly mark your blocks. Especially if you don't understand the rules of if then else scoping

Comment: I don't think indentation technically has any effect on the scoping in java, it's just convention. Rather, you _need_ the braces around the else statement to have multiple lines executed as part of the else.

Comment: Alright so I applied correct indentation but its not the issue, the second System.in.read() still does not show up on terminal, if you actually run the code THATS the question i'm asking why isnt it prompting another input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, as @GhostCat mentioned, you should put brackets around your if and else cases, otherwise the second read will happen regardless of the if statement

```
if (ch == answer) {
    // your if code here
else {
    // your else code here
}
```

Second, if you want it run indefinitely until they give a right answer, you need some kind of loop. In this case, you probably want a while loop. This would replace the if statement

```
while (ch != answer) {
    // ask for retry
}
// They were right!
```

The code after the closing bracket will only run once the condition of the while loop is false (in this case, when ch is equal to answer). Meaning, at this point you can handle the correct answer case. Meanwhile, if they input the wrong answer, the program will loop and they will be prompted to try again.

EDIT: As to why the original code wasn't waiting for a second input and just stopping, inputting the first character in the command line actually adds an extra carriage return/new line character to the end of input, so the second read immediately consumes this new line character and proceeds (which in the initial code there's nothing else to do, so it quits).

Comment: I'm trying to use what I learn so far from a book, I'm just really confused as to why the second ch = (char) System.in.read  is not showing up on terminal when I placed it under try again:

Comment: `System.in.read` doesn't show anything, it just reads from input. It looks like in your code, the "try again" print is using `println`, which prints a new line at the end. If you're expecting it to be waiting on the same line, then that should just be `print`

Comment: Still dosent work, basically the code just ends eventhough I clearly stated I wanted to enter another input. Don't know why its not registering

Comment: It ends as soon as it prints the try again message?

Comment: Yes, it just returns back to:  Brads-MacBook-Pro:desktop Brad$

Comment: Or do you put in a new character and then it ends? Because if this is the case, that's expected, you're not doing anything after your second read unless you're using the while loop as I mentioned.

Comment: Add a print after the second read, just something like `System.out.println(ch);` to see what it thinks ch is at the end.

Comment: Apparently the while loop solved the issue. May I ask why did the second read not do anything ?

Comment: So I just ran it myself, hitting enter registers a new line character in the input, as I thought might be happening. So the second read just reads the existing 'new line' character immediately

Comment: If you need to read command line input in this way, I would highly recommend the Scanner class, it provides much better packaging and utility. A basic google search can tell you how to use it. Though I understand you're just messing around for learning purposes.

Comment: How is it reading enter for the second one before I even press enter ?

Comment: Your enter press from the first input passes whatever character you input as well as the new line character from hitting enter, and it just sits in your input until the program uses it (at the second read)

Comment: Ohh that explains alot, think that's actually mentioned in my book just did'nt know what it meant. Something to do with line buffering and a carriage return ?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it.

Comment: Alright thanks mate ! Your detailed answers and help is highly appreciated probably one of the best that actually answered my confusion

Comment: Basically command line sends stuff to input one line at a time, but the end of the line has a carriage return (or new line) character at the end, so you have to account for that. And no problem, good luck and welcome to programming!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
            char ch, answer = 'K';
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
            System.out.print("Can you guess it: ");
            ch = s.next().charAt(0);
            if(ch == answer){
                    System.out.println(" *** YOU ARE RIGHT *** ");
            } else{
                    System.out.println("Please try again: ");
                    ch = s.next().charAt(0);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ch == answer) 
     System.out.println(" *** YOU ARE RIGHT *** ");

       else System.out.println("Please try again: ");
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
```

is the equivalent of

```
if(ch == answer) {}
    System.out.println(" *** YOU ARE RIGHT *** ");
} else {
    System.out.println("Please try again: ");
}
ch = (char) System.in.read();
```

Indentation has no effect semantically nor syntactically. It's just a convention but it has no effect on your program (in contrast to python).

You should loop the program:

```
while(ch != answer) {
    ch = (char) System.in.read();
    ....
}
```

However, this lacks EOF handling. It's better to use something like this:

```
while(true) {
   int ch = System.in.read();
   if(ch < 0) {
      System.out.println("Bye!");
   }

   if((char)ch == answer) {
      System.out.println("YOU ARE RIGHT");
      break;
   }

   System.out.println("Please try again: ");
}
```

Also, bear in mind that read() reads only one byte which depending on how you input the data can be confusing because terminals usually buffer input until you press enter... not all terminals do this but most do it. You might be better of with using `System.console` which provides a `readLine` method. However, `System.console` won't work if no console is attached to stdin (such as when piping input to stdin, but for your case that's not a problem because I don't think your program is intended to be used through pipes). You can use `System.console.readLine()` and then strip away unwanted characters using the `trim` method of `String`.